# Why is this recursive function in Haskell so slow?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to imitate the Sieve for finding all the prime less than some number using Haskell. I have found other Haskell program that use the Sieve method with great speed. However the following recursive function I wrote is very slow. The code is as follows

```
sieve' :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]

sieve' n 1 = [2 .. n]

sieve' n (k + 1) | [x | x <- sieve' n k, x == k + 1] == [] = sieve' n k

    |otherwise = [x | x <- sieve' n k,  x == k + 1 || not (mod x (k + 1) == 0)]



sieve :: Integer -> [Integer]

sieve n = sieve' n n
```

Sieve 20 takes about 2 minutes. Sieve 30 still hasn't finished while I am writing this question.

Can anyone explain why this recursive function is so slow. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: As the ultimate authority on Eratosthenes' sieve in Haskell you should take a look at Melissa O'Neill's article (http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3127) in the Journal of Functional Programming (2009). There should be a few more tricks in it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your second clause of `sieve'` function is making the recursive call (`sieve' n k`) twice, thus making your algorithm perform in exponential time.

To fix this problem you can bind the term to some name, thus ensuring it's evaluated once:

```
sieve' n (k + 1) | [x | x <- rec, x == k + 1] == [] = rec
    |otherwise = [x | x <- rec,  x == k + 1 || not (mod x (k + 1) == 0)]
  where
    rec = sieve' n k
```

***Update in response to a comment asking why the compiler does not do this automatically:***

This kind of transformation, called CSE (common subexpression elimination), is not an optimisation in general, but rather a trade-off between time and space usage, so the decision is better left for a programmer.

Googling for "CSE" reveals some interesting discussions, one of which references [this very good example](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/slpj-book-1987/PAGES/405.HTM) from 1987 book by Simon Peyton Jones called "The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages" (Oh my, this book is almost as old as I am)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the problem. It runs much faster now.

Comment: I find it odd that the compiler missed this optimisation.